# Derivative of $\frac x {\log |x|}$ without using L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, limits-without-lhopital

Consider the function $f:x \neq 0 \mapsto \frac x {\log |x|},  0 \mapsto 0$.  What is its derivative at $x = 0$?

I was only able to solve this using L'Hopital's rule.  I request:

1. Verification or critique of my solution
2. Is it possible to solve without L'Hopital's rule?

---

**Proof:**

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {\frac h {\log h} - 0}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac 1 {\log h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac 0 {1/h} \tag{by L'Hopital's Rule} \\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Similarly,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {\frac h {\log -h} - 0}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac 1 {\log -h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac 0 {1/h} \tag{by L'Hopital's Rule} \\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Since the left and right limits are equal, the limit is defined, and is $0$.

---

## Update

With help from Thomas Andrews' comment, I replace my (mis?)application of L'Hopital's Rule with the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for all $R$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $h \neq 0 \in [-\delta, \delta], g(k+h) \geq R$.  Then $\lim_{x \to k} \frac 1 {g(x)} = 0.$

**Proof:** For any $\epsilon > 0 $, choose $R > 1/\epsilon$.  Then for all $h \neq 0 \in [-\delta, \delta],$ $$\frac 1 {|g(k+h)|} \leq \frac 1 R < \epsilon.$$

Comment: L'Hopital doesn't apply here, because $\lim_{h\to0}\log|h|\to-\infty,$ making your limit of the form $1/-\infty,$ which is not indeterminate form. But the limit is obviously $0$ here, since all limits of that form are $0$.

Comment: In general, your proof would mean $\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{g(h)}\to 0$ for any $g(h).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you prove limits of form $\frac 1 \infty$, with or without L'Hopital's Rule? Intuitively, of course, the result is clear.  What is the proof? Re $g(h)$, my claim is only for cases where $g(h) \to \infty$, in which case I think the result that $\lim \frac 1 {g(h)} = 0$ is indeed true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews theoretically L'Hopital's rule does indeed apply as the conditions of the theorem to imply $\lim f'/g'=\lim f/g$ require either $0/0$ or $g\to \infty$ independent of $f$. However it would be pointless to use it in case of finite $f$ since the limit will be zero. But OP had a valid, if unnecessary, use of L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've revised, can you take a look?

Comment: If $|g(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to0,$ then we can find, for any $\epsilon>0$ a $\delta$ such that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)|>\frac1{\epsilon}$ and hence $\left|\frac1{g(x)}\right|<\epsilon.$

Comment: I had forgotten L'Hopital applies in this case. Still, it is highly unnecessary.